# Visible/interactable folders which are definitely recognized as inexistent by Windows on an external drive?

Tags: windows, windows-11

What could possibly caused the following situation?:

Windows 11 shows and allows the interaction with folders which are definitely recognized as inexistent on an external drive.

I wonder if this behaviour is actually repairable with a specific command for the external drive?
Any known commands that I tried so far to delete these folders directly would never work I guess, because for Windows 11 there is simply nothing  there.
A system reboot didn't solve this behaviour.

Comment: Boot with a Linux USB (Say Ubuntu) and see if it sees the folders.  Delete from there. You may need to disable Secure Boot temporarily to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Finally one idea I had was succesful on Windows 11:

At first I wasn't sure if this is realisable, but 7-Zip for example has this option integrated directly: "Delete files after compression". So one solution that works in Windows could be:
Compress the inexistent folder directory into an archive with that option enabled using 7-Zip and the folder would be gone.